# What is a good optimization algorithm/tool for otimization on Partially Ordered set?

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Actually I'm interested to minimize following kind of functions:

$f: U \rightarrow V$

where:

$U$ is a vector space and
 $V$ is a Ordered vector space, i mean Partially Ordered Vector space.

Special Case :
 $U$ is any set and $V$ is a Partially Ordered set.

What kind of Optimization algorithm works here? What is the starting point. Is there any ready made optimization toolbox available for this?

Thanks in advance !!!

FYI:

After googling a lot. I found this[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_optimization] is the closest thing I'm searching for. The references given in that page are really helpful.

Comment: Do you really need this much abstraction or do you have a more specific class of problem in mind that you want to solve?

Comment: @icurays1 Actually I'm trying to minimizing a loss function defined as $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow A$ where A is a partially ordered set because every loss (i.e negative incentive) is not comparable to every other loss.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_optimization).  I've never worked with it so I can't offer any more advice, unfortunately.

Comment: No such algorithm is mentioned in the given Wiki link to solve it...thank you @icurays1 any way !!!